# MySQL - How to control `numeric` column of one table from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following:

```
book(book_id,book_name,quantity)
donor(book_id)
acquisition(donor_id,book_id,booksDonated)
```

When I insert a data in acquisition, the value of `booksDonated` must update to the given `book_id`'s `quantity`.
I tried learning triggers, but it turns out it cannot pass variable, since i am working in PHP. 
How can I insert and update(with the given data of the table) at the same time. 
PS. Please add a query of it if it's something complex.

Comment: Update book table with book first and then use that book id to update the donor table. Whats your exact problem.

Comment: I edited my answer. I also have a transaction table. which it have the `donor` and the `book`. When I add a the transaction, the quantity of the book can also be updated regardless of how many I input in the transaction.

Comment: So, the acquisition must also contain quantity, right? And donor must contain donor_id? Maybe you need a donor table and a donation table?

Comment: Nope, it must be add. So when another donor wants to donate, the quantity of the book must increment if it is the same book he wants to donate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more complete answer. First, you need to create the following table structure in your database (creating tables, primary keys and autoincrement fields).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acquisition` (
  `acquistion_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `donor_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `book_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `booksDonated` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (
  `book_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `book_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `donor` (
  `donor_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `acquisition` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`acquistion_id`);

ALTER TABLE `book` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`);

ALTER TABLE `donor` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`donor_id`);

ALTER TABLE `acquisition` MODIFY `acquistion_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `book` MODIFY `book_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `donor` MODIFY `donor_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Now, based on this structure, you can use the following functions to

Add a book 
Add a donor (2 different donor's in the example) 
Add a book's acquisition

```
function addBook($con, $name)
{
    $id = -1;
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `book` (`book_id`, `book_name`, `quantity`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '0');";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (mysqli_error($con) == 0)
    {
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    }
    return $id;
}
function addDonor($con, $name)
{
    $id = -1;
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `donor` (`donor_id`, `name`) VALUES ('1', '$name');";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (mysqli_error($con) == 0)
    {
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    }
    return $id;
}
function addAcquisition($con, $book_id, $donor_id, $quantity)
{
    $id = 0;
    $book_id = intval($book_id);
    $donor_id = intval($donor_id);
    $quantity = intval($quantity);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `acquisition` (`acquistion_id`, `donor_id`, `book_id`, `booksDonated`) VALUES (NULL, '{$donor_id}', '{$book_id}', '{$quantity}');";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (mysqli_error($con) != 0)
    {
    $id = -1;
    }

//This SQL updates the current book count with the newly donated quantity, so they stay in sync.

    $query = "UPDATE `book` SET `quantity` = (`quantity` + '{$quantity}') WHERE `book_id` = '{$book_id}';";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if (mysqli_error($con) == 0)
    {
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    }
    return $id;
}
```

Now, using the functions, you can create a book, one or more donors and their acquisitions.

```
// Fill your DB values here
$host = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$database = '';

// Connect to the DB
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

// Add a book. $book_id contains the new book's ID
$book_id = addBook($con, 'This is the book\'s name');

// Add a donor. $book_id contains the new donor's ID
$donor1_id = addDonor($con, 'This is the first Donor\'s name');

// Add another book. $book_id contains the second donor's ID
$donor2_id = addDonor($con, 'This is the second Donor\'s name');

addAcquisition($con, $book_id, $donor1_id, 5);
addAcquisition($con, $book_id, $donor2_id, 10);

// After running this code, there'll be 15 in the quantity field (5 from Donor 1 + 10 from Donor 2) and 2 acquistion records
```

Comment: I like how you manage to shorten the code! Though I didn't use most of them, but one more question. what is this `function addDonor($con, $name)` like, it is java? because i don't think it is php

Comment: addDonor is a function I created for adding a donor to the database, so that you can retrieve it's ID. If you already have donors on your database, you don't need it. Just supply the ID to addAcquisition();

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `UPDATE` query, like the following:

`UPDATE book SET Quantity = Quantity + 'BOOKSDONATED' WHERE book_id = ID`

This way, you add BOOKSDONATED books (the number of books the donor is giving) to the existing quantity of books with book_id = ID

You then insert a record on the acquisition table using the books_I'd and donor_I'd.

Comment: Can i use double query in PHP in one go? Like adding the transaction plus updating the book table?

Comment: @WTFZane No. See transactions in MySQL

Comment: Hey ok ok, the answer make sense just now. But how will the book identify what table is the 'BOOKSDONATED'?

Comment: @WTFZane It's your database. You tell us!

Comment: Thanks for your eagerness to help me @Strawberry, but the BOOKSDONATED must be in `Acquisition` table.

Comment: BOOKSDONATED is the number of books the donor gives. It's a number. As for identifying the book, you either have to know the book_id in advance or, if creating a new book, you need to use the mysqli_insert_id() function to find it.